# Add GeoJSON layer to OpenLayers 3.16 from GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs, json

I try to be as simple as possible with my problem. It's just to display a json layer from my Geoserver on a OSM layer with a ol3.16 page.

I take the example  from this page: http://openlayers.org/en/latest/example … -wfs.html

I take the code of this page and change ONLY the geoserver query to my layer. I get the OSM layer and nothing else.

I open the inspector window in Firefox for both pages (the example and mine).

With the example page, the query call is done and I get a response of 200ko. With my page, the call is done and the response size is 0ko.

To check my query I copy-paste the url from the inspector window in the adress bar, and then I get the json data. If I save it in a file, I have no problem to loads it in another ol3.16 page as a local file.

Then, the query is well formed, it's sent to geoserver and Geoserver dont sent the response only to my page. Anyone have an idea why????

Comment: Do the demos work from your geoserver instance? Possible CORS issue, but difficult to say unless you show the actual configuration / query.

Answer (score 1):

the problem could be from the CORS not enabled, if your web page is in a web server not in geoserver, you can either:

1- put your web page in the www folder inside geoserver/data_dir and lauch it from there

2 - or if you need to launch it from a web server ( apache for example ) you will have to enable JSONP in your geoserver configuration like this :

- go to yourGeoServer\webapps\geoserver\WEB-INF\web.xml
- look for JSONP and uncomment the balises

> ```
>  <context-param>
>     <param-name>ENABLE_JSONP</param-name>
>     <param-value>true</param-value>
>  </context-param>
> ```

- now in your JS code change the format of data to text/javascript instead of application/json. and add in your ajax call

  dataType: 'jsonp'

now restart geoserver and your WFS layer will appear

Comment: I put it in the WWW folder ans it's working
Thanks a lot!